# FlutterFire_UI Package How to remove "Don't Have an account? register" text

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I have been following this documentation and was able to customize the background color, add a custom image and edit the subtitle and footers using the builders, but I am stuck on how to edit the default text that FlutterFire_UI has in their `SignInScreen()` Widget.

[image]

I want to possibly edit the "Sign in" text and the "Don't have an account? Register" text. The register option will not be needed if I am not using email and password and just using Google, Facebook, and Apple Sign in methods.

Looking at source code for the constructor for the SignInScreen() widget I dont see anything related to either of those text fields:

```
 const SignInScreen({
    Key? key,
    List<ProviderConfiguration>? providerConfigs,
    FirebaseAuth? auth,
    this.headerMaxExtent,
    this.headerBuilder,
    this.sideBuilder,
    this.oauthButtonVariant = OAuthButtonVariant.icon_and_text,
    this.desktopLayoutDirection,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset = false,
    this.showAuthActionSwitch,
    this.email,
    this.subtitleBuilder,
    this.footerBuilder,
    this.loginViewKey,
    this.actions = const [],
    this.breakpoint = 800,
    this.styles,
  }) : super(key: key, providerConfigs: providerConfigs, auth: auth);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfhVd.png
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme from the Material wrapper?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. I assumed changing theme just changed colors, can you remove widgets as well?

Answer (score 2):

`showAuthActionSwitch: false,` option will solve your problem.

```js
return SignInScreen({
   showAuthActionSwitch: false,
   // ...
})
```

Comment: Please write high quality answers.